# Hollow square function with two inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been struggling to create a function that can put out a default hollow square of 5x5 but then also take in 2 inputs.

Here's the question:
create a charsqr.py function that when imported will result in the following:

Program:

```
def main():
    charsqr()
    charsqr(4)
    charsqr(3,'#')
main()
```

Result:

```
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
****
*  *
*  *
****
###
# #
###
```

Here's my code:

```
def charsqr(chars,sym):

if type(chars) = int and type(sym)=str:
    print(str(sym)*chars)
    for i in range(chars-2):
        print(str(sym)+" "*(chars-2)+str(sym))
    print(str(sym)*chars)        


else:
    print("*"*5)
    for i in range(5):
        print("*"+" "*3+"*")
    print("*"*5)
```

I've been fiddling around with the if statement as I've been getting "missing 2 positional arguments" error. I know how to create a hollow square, just not sure how to get the program to print the default square and then a square with the given "chars" without needing a "sym".

Any feedback is appreciated ! :)

Comment: what you need are default arguments: "charsqr(chars=None, sym=None)". Then you could test the value of the arguments within the function. If they are none, you can ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're complicating this way too much, a simple:

```
def draw_square(size=5, edge="*", fill=" "):
    hollow = size - 2  # just so we don't calculate the hollow part each time
    print(edge * size)  # top part
    for _ in range(hollow):  # iterate until the last line
        print(edge + fill * hollow + edge)  # middle part
    print(edge * size)  # bottom part
```

Should do the trick. You can even change the 'hollow' part to some character.

Comment: Omg thank you! I feel so dumb, I really need to practise more. This works, thanks so much for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You apparently want a function that uses an asterisk if no character is stated, and uses size 5 if no size is stated. That is what default parameters are for in Python:

```
def charsqr(chars=5, sym='*'):
```

Then calling `charsqr()` is the same as `charsqr(5, '*')`, and calling `charsqr(4)` is the same as `charsqr(4, '*')`. Calling `charsqr(3, '#')` uses no defaults.

Note that the code you show has bad indentation and will give a syntax error. Indent the lines of your function (everything but the `def` line). Also replace the `=` symbols in your `if` line with `==`. With those three changes, your code works and gives the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I see, I really need to go through my function notes again, I forgot you could do that ! Sorry for the syntax errors, new to this site and wrote my code in a rush, but thanks for all the feedback :)